# Retrofit doesn't send POST request

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I can't seem to get the POST request working with Retrofit. My code:

ApiService.kt contains a function

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("resume")
suspend fun resumeAsync(@Body request: JSONObject): Response<String>
```

Then in my ListViewModel.kt I have a function

```
fun resume(id: String) {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        try {
            val paramObject = JSONObject()
            paramObject.put("id", id)

            val response = Api.retrofitService.resumeAsync(paramObject)
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                _status.value = "Success: Resumed!"
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            _status.value = "Failure: " + e.message
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this not working? I don't get any error or response back. If I put Log.i in the Api or the view model it says it's triggered

By debugging I found out this error:

```
2020-09-15 11:40:10.904 20622-20622/com.example.app I/NETWORK: Unable to create @Body converter for class org.json.JSONObject (parameter #1) for method ApiService.resumeAsync
```

I am using Moshi as well

```
private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
.add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
.build()

private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()
```

Comment: `response.isSuccessful` == false?

Comment: Nope, nothing written there

Comment: This looks fine for me, I suggest to debug it and check if it's not hanging, maybe the request never finishes? Or maybe some permission issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding a logging interceptor to your okHttp client and check what you're sending and receiving in the request.

```
val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
```

Is the url/endpoint correct?

Are you missing a "/" at the end of the url?

Have you declared internet permission in the manifest?

etc.

**Solution**:

Wrapping request body:

```
@Body body: RequestBody 

val body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), obj.toString())
```

Comment: 2020-09-15 11:40:10.904 20622-20622/com.example.app I/NETWORK: Unable to create @Body converter for class org.json.JSONObject (parameter #1)
        for method ApiService.resumeAsync

Comment: does your retrofit object have a converter factory? 
 .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())

Comment: Yes, but it's using Moshi .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))

Comment: You can try wrapping your request body like this:

`@Body body: RequestBody`  

`val body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), obj.toString())`

Answer (score 2):

If you need to receive raw json then use `Call<*>`

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("resume")
fun resumeAsync(@Body request: JSONObject): retrofit2.Call<String>
```

Inside coroutine (without `suspend` keyword above)

```
// or .awaitResponse() to get Response<*> object
val response = Api.retrofitService.resumeAsync(paramObject).await()
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you debug on this line

```
if (response.isSuccessful) {
```

try to check the variable `response`;

Or you shoud check whether the server is work, check it with other tools like `Postman`

Answer (score 0):

So I solved my problem by doing what @Paul Nitu recommended

```
val body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), obj.toString())
```